# divide by previous element by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
origdate <- c(rep('2011-01-01',5), rep('2011-02-01',4), rep('2011-03-01',3))
date <- c('2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', 
   '2011-05-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-05-01',
     '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-05-01')
A <- data.frame(origdate, date, bal=20:31)
A$origdate <- as.Date(A$origdate)
A$date <- as.Date(A$date)
A
         origdate       date bal
    1  2011-01-01 2011-01-01  20
    2  2011-01-01 2011-02-01  21
    3  2011-01-01 2011-03-01  22
    4  2011-01-01 2011-04-01  23
    5  2011-01-01 2011-05-01  24
    6  2011-02-01 2011-02-01  25
    7  2011-02-01 2011-03-01  26
    8  2011-02-01 2011-04-01  27
    9  2011-02-01 2011-05-01  28
    10 2011-03-01 2011-03-01  29
    11 2011-03-01 2011-04-01  30
    12 2011-03-01 2011-05-01  31
```

What I want to do is divide the `bal` by the previous `bal` for each increment of `date`, but not when `origdate` changes. So what I want to obtain is shown below in the column `dbal`:

```
     origdate       date bal     dbal
1  2011-01-01 2011-01-01  20       NA
2  2011-01-01 2011-02-01  21 1.050000
3  2011-01-01 2011-03-01  22 1.047619
4  2011-01-01 2011-04-01  23 1.045455
5  2011-01-01 2011-05-01  24 1.043478
6  2011-02-01 2011-02-01  25       NA
7  2011-02-01 2011-03-01  26 1.040000
8  2011-02-01 2011-04-01  27 1.038462
9  2011-02-01 2011-05-01  28 1.037037
10 2011-03-01 2011-03-01  29       NA
11 2011-03-01 2011-04-01  30 1.034483
12 2011-03-01 2011-05-01  31 1.033333
```

I could write a complicated double loop to do this, but is there a simpler way to do it in `R`?

Comment: `ave(A$bal,A$origdate,FUN=function(x) c(NA,x[-1]/x[-length(x)]))`.

Comment: And data.table `setDT(A)[, bal / shift(bal), by = origdate]`

Comment: The last two comments look answer-worthy, @nicola and Pierre

Comment: Will `A$date` always increment? Is there anything that needs to be taken account for `A$date`? Aside any loop, simply translating your goal in R code, you have (i) a condition: `c(FALSE, A$origdate[-1] == A$origdate[-nrow(A)])`, (ii) a value if TRUE: `A$bal / c(NA, A$bal[-nrow(A)])` and, (iii) a value if FALSE: `NA_real_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% group_by(origdate) %>%
    mutate(dbal = bal / lag(bal))
# Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
# Groups: origdate [3]
# 
#      origdate       date   bal     dbal
#        <date>     <date> <int>    <dbl>
# 1  2011-01-01 2011-01-01    20       NA
# 2  2011-01-01 2011-02-01    21 1.050000
# 3  2011-01-01 2011-03-01    22 1.047619
# 4  2011-01-01 2011-04-01    23 1.045455
# 5  2011-01-01 2011-05-01    24 1.043478
# 6  2011-02-01 2011-02-01    25       NA
# 7  2011-02-01 2011-03-01    26 1.040000
# 8  2011-02-01 2011-04-01    27 1.038462
# 9  2011-02-01 2011-05-01    28 1.037037
# 10 2011-03-01 2011-03-01    29       NA
# 11 2011-03-01 2011-04-01    30 1.034483
# 12 2011-03-01 2011-05-01    31 1.033333
```